# Accessing JButtons in tabbed pane

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a tabbed pane for the amount of rooms that I have and I am creating a light button for each light that each room has and adding it to the tabbed pane.

How can I distinguish between these JButtons(lights) in each tabbed pane? say I wanted to do something to light 2 in room2(tabbed pane 2) how can I call it?.

At the moment I am just creating a JButton called light, attaching the event class, and adding it to the tabbed pane?. The event class knows what room and light it is, but I need to know how to access it from outside the event class.

Like if I wanted to stimulate the actionevent of that button without it being clicked. The reason being is I have a client version of the program and a master, and when something happens on the client it needs to happen on the master. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class MasterGUI extends GUI{
      public static ArrayList<Rooms> rooms;

public MasterGUI(){
    rooms = Building.getRoomList();
}

public static void UpDateGuiLabels(final int roomNo){   
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            try{ 
                rooms.get(roomNo - 1).roomHeatLoss();
                solarLabels.get(roomNo - 1).setText("Room BTU is: " + round(rooms.get(roomNo - 1).getHeatLoss()));
            }catch (RuntimeException e){        
            }
        }
    });
}

public void initComponents(){
    JFrame master = new JFrame("Solar Master Control Panel"); 
    master.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container content = master.getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    for(Rooms room : rooms){
        JPanel tmpPanel = new JPanel();
        String roomName = room.getName();
        int roomId = room.getId();
        tabbedPane.addTab(roomName + " Room " + roomId, tmpPanel);
        JPanel lightsPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        lightsPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 5));

        for(Lights light : room.roomLights){
            int lightId = light.getId();
            JButton lights = new JButton("Off");
            lights.setBackground(Color.red);
            lights.addActionListener(new LightButtonEvent(roomId, lightId));
            lights.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 30));
            lights.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
            JLabel lightLabel = new JLabel("Light" + lightId);
            Font curFont = lightLabel.getFont();
            lightLabel.setFont(new Font(curFont.getFontName(), curFont.getStyle(), 13));
            lightsPane.add(lightLabel);
            lightsPane.add(lights);
            ((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(roomId - 1)).add(lightsPane);
        }

        solarLabels.add(new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER));
        UpDateGuiLabels(roomId);
        JSlider heaterSlider = new JSlider(68, 73);
        heaterSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        heaterSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        heaterSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
        heaterSlider.addChangeListener(new HeaterSliderEvent(roomId));
        heaterSlider.setEnabled(false);
        JButton heater = new JButton("Heater");
        heater.setBackground(Color.red);
        heater.addActionListener(new HeaterButtonEvent(roomId, heaterSlider));
        ((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(roomId - 1)).add(heater);
        ((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(roomId - 1)).add(heaterSlider);
        ((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(roomId - 1)).add(solarLabels.get(roomId - 1));
    }
        master.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        master.setSize(800, 600);
        content.add(tabbedPane);
        master.setVisible(true);
}
```

EVENT CLASS FOR LIGHTS

```
public class LightButtonEvent implements ActionListener{
  ArrayList<Rooms> rooms;
  int lightNumber;
  int roomNumber;

public LightButtonEvent(int room, int light){
    lightNumber = light;
    roomNumber = room;
    rooms = Building.getRoomList();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(rooms.get(roomNumber - 1).roomLights.get(lightNumber - 1).getLightStatus() == true){
        rooms.get(roomNumber - 1).roomLights.get(lightNumber - 1).setLightOff();
            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("Off");
                ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.red);
                    MasterGUI.UpDateGuiLabels(roomNumber);
    }else{
        rooms.get(roomNumber - 1).roomLights.get(lightNumber - 1).setLightOn();
            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("On");
                ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.green);
                    MasterGUI.UpDateGuiLabels(roomNumber);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [referencing a button in a tabbedpane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828989/referencing-a-button-in-a-tabbedpane)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why on earth would you try to access the button and fire the event. The UI is only a view on the data. Why not manipulating the data directly ? If you figure out a way to find that button and trigger a click on it (which is not that hard), you are screwed when you decide to change your layout afterwards.

So just share your data behind your UI between master and client, and make sure your UI is updated when something is changed on the data (and vice versa, the UI should update the data when the user makes changes in the UI). That way you can share the state.

Try a quick search on Google for MVC (model-view-controller) if you want some more reading on this.

But if still want to do a click, each button has a [`doClick`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29) method which does the same thing as if the user had pressed and released the button (quote from the javadoc).

Comment: @Robin and JtabbedPane is broken CardLayout (out of up_votes for today)

Comment: @mKorbel that depends. Even with a CardLayout you would need to place buttons somewhere to switch between the layouts. Tabs could certainly make sense since everybody understands that when you click the tab that tab will become active. It might be less straightforward that the buttons somewhere in your UI will change the contents of another container