# referencing a button in a tabbedpane

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtabbedpane

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing JButtons in tabbed pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827239/accessing-jbuttons-in-tabbed-pane)

Hi I am creating Jbuttons and adding them to pane and then adding the pane to a tabbedpane, how can I reference the buttons from elsewhere? so reference one of the buttons in the tabbed pane? like tabbedpane.pane.button?? Any help is appreciated

```
public void initComponents(){
    JFrame master = new JFrame("Solar Master Control Panel"); 
    master.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container content = master.getContentPane();
    content.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    for(Rooms room : rooms){
        JPanel tmpPanel = new JPanel();
        String roomName = room.getName();
        int roomId = room.getId();
        tabbedPane.addTab(roomName + " Room " + roomId, tmpPanel);
        JPanel lightsPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        lightsPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 5));

        for(Lights light : room.roomLights){
            int lightId = light.getId();
            JButton lights = new JButton("Off");
            lights.setBackground(Color.red);
            lights.addActionListener(new LightButtonEvent(roomId, lightId));
            lights.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 30));
            lights.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
            JLabel lightLabel = new JLabel("Light" + lightId);
            Font curFont = lightLabel.getFont();
            lightLabel.setFont(new Font(curFont.getFontName(), curFont.getStyle(), 13));
            lightsPane.add(lightLabel);
            lights.add(lights);
            lightsPane.add(lights);
            tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, lightspane);
        }

        solarLabels.add(new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER));
        UpDateGuiLabels(roomId);
        JSlider heaterSlider = new JSlider(68, 73);
        heaterSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
        heaterSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
        heaterSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(1);
        heaterSlider.addChangeListener(new HeaterSliderEvent(roomId));
        heaterSlider.setEnabled(false);
        JButton heater = new JButton("Heater");
        heater.setBackground(Color.red);
        heater.addActionListener(new HeaterButtonEvent(roomId, heaterSlider));
        ((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(roomId - 1)).add(heater);
        ((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(roomId - 1)).add(heaterSlider);
        ((JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(roomId - 1)).add(solarLabels.get(roomId - 1));
    }
        master.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        master.setSize(800, 600);
        content.add(tabbedPane);
        master.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking the same question here twice? If so, why not simply edit and improve the original post rather than needlessly divide the discussion?

Comment: Nice catch @HovercraftFullOfEels . I find his previous question much better as it illustrates what he wants to do and why. So voted to close this one, and answered the other question

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to access your components. One way to to maintain references to your controls. In this case, you would need a collection for each control, where perhaps an index is used to refer to the correct tabbed pane.

The other approach is to use the `name` property, and find the component using a path-like expression of names. Note that there is no API-wide support this approach, so you would need to write your own name-path walking function:

```
Component findComponent(Component root, String... namePath) {
  assert root != null;
  assert namePath != null;
  Component current = root;
  for (int i = 0; i < namePath.length; ++i) {
    if (!(current instanceof Container)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot follow path at [" + i + "] -- " + namePath[i]);
    }
    Container container = (Container) current;
    for (int j = 0; j < container.getComponentCount(); ++j) {
      if (namePath[i].equals(container.getComponent(j).getName())) {
        current = container.getComponent(j);
        break;
      }
    } // each component within container
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No component named " + namePath[i] + " found.");
  } // each name in name path.
  return current;
}
```

You would need to set the name on each component. Afterwards, you would be able to find the 'off' button, for example, with something like:

```
JButton button = (JButton) findComponent(masterFrame, "rooms", "Room 12", "OffButton");
```

If the tabbed pane's name is 'rooms', and each tab is named the same as it is titled.

Comment: Why not recursively call the findComponent function. Now you enforce that the button is added directly to the container.